# how to use --enable-media-stream switch properly in jcef

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, chromium-embedded

In a program I am developing using jcef, I want to allow the camera to be used inside. I am trying to give `--enable-media-stream` switch for the program that I am building using jcef. I am tried to turn on switch with the following cases:

```
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = useOSR;
        settings.command_line_args_disabled = false;
        String[] args = new String[]{
                "--enable-media-stream=true"
               // "--enable-media-steam",
               // "enable-media-stream", "1"
        };

        cefApp = CefApp.getInstance(args, settings);
```

Program gives

**[1031/094701.279:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Permission denied", source: theUrl**

error in every cases.
However, the camera is allowed if I run *.jar app from command line with: "java -jar appName.jar --enable-media-stream" command.
What might be the issue here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with next code:

```
CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null) {
            @Override
            public void onBeforeCommandLineProcessing(String process_type, CefCommandLine command_line) {
                super.onBeforeCommandLineProcessing(process_type, command_line);
                if (process_type.isEmpty()) {
                    command_line.appendSwitchWithValue("enable-media-stream","true");
                }
            }
        });
```